# How to install Windows Updates on HyperV host with no downtime, without using live migration?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-update, windows-server-2022

Is there a way to install Windows Updates on a HyperV Host, e.g. Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, without downtime, unless you use live migration?  Any suggestions here would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please provide more information about how many Hyper-V Hosts there are, if they are configured in a Failover Cluster, and if you use Hyper-V Replica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. If you need to perform maintenance on the Hyper-V Host without having the Virtual Machines be unavailable, you would need to have a cluster of Hyper-V Hosts and in Failover Cluster Manager, you would drain the roles of the Hyper-V Host that you want to perform maintenance (right click on the Hyper-V Host you want to install updates on, and click Drain Roles). When you click Drain Roles, the virtual machines will be live migrated to another Hyper-V Host in the Failover Cluster.

https://rdr-it.com/en/hyper-v-cluster-maintenance-of-a-node/